# How to use context in *ngTemplateOutlet with custom Directive in Angular with Material Tables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular2-directives

Used Framework: Angular 8 with Material Design

I have made a table-template for reusing my structures in different components, so I don´t have to rebuild it again. 
The table can be used and modified on every component and on desktop view it looks as I expected. 
Now I added a mobile-Header-Row which should look different and I hoped using *ngTemplateOutlet with a "isMobile"-Property in the Context could solve my problem. 
But in the component I only receive the data, not the context!?

Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

Used ng-template in my component, where I use my table-component, but it shows nothing. Using ng-container shows me the provided Data.

Part of my template-table:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{ headerValue.field }}-filter" *ngFor="let headerValue of headerValues">
<ng-container *ngIf="headerValue.isSearchable">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [class.hidden-below-lg]="headerValue.isMobileHeaderRow">
        <trp-input-field
            formControlName="{{ headerValue.field }}"
            placeholder="{{ 'SEARCH' | translate }}"
            class="dark"
        ></trp-input-field>
    </th>
    <td
        mat-cell
        *matCellDef="let element"
        [class.hidden-below-lg]="headerValue.isMobileHeaderRow"
        [innerHTML]="
            (element[headerValue.field] ? element[headerValue.field].toString() : '') | translate
        "
    ></td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!headerValue.isSearchable">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
</ng-container>
```

in my Component:

```
    <app-table-header
    [isSearchable]="true"
    name="{{ 'TARGET_AGREEMENT.STORES.FIELDS.NAME' | translate }}"
    field="name"
    [isMobileHeaderRow]="true"
    width="260px"
>
    <ng-container *appColumnFormat="let targetAgreement">
        {{ targetAgreement.name }} -
        {{ targetAgreement.rmsId }}
    </ng-container>

</app-table-header>
```

my  appColumnFormat-Directive used in my table-header-Directive

```
@Directive({
selector: '[appColumnFormat]',
})
export class TableColumnFormatDirective {
}

my table-header-Directive

@Directive({
selector: 'trp-table-header',
})
export class TableHeaderDirective {
@Input() public name: string;
@Input() public field: string;
@Input() public width: string;
@Input() public isSearchable = false;
@Input() public isMobileHeaderRow = false;
@Input() public sorting = (_data: any, _sortHeaderId: string): 
string => {
    return '';
};

@ContentChild(TableColumnFormatDirective, { static: false, read: 
TemplateRef })
public template: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

I expect to have an context-object in my Component like
-->
`<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let isMobile" [class.hidden-below-lg]="headerValue.isMobileHeaderRow" [innerHTML]="(element[headerValue.field] ? element[headerValue.field].toString() : '') | translate "></td>
or something`

At the beginning I followed this Tutorial: 
https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/May/29/angular-ng-template-outlet.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

In your *app-table-header* component's view, instead of using innerHTML, use *ngTemplateOutlet

## app-table-header

```
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
        [class.hidden-below-lg]="headerValue.isMobileHeaderRow">
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: { $implicit: element }"></ng-container>
</td>
```

The context you pass in this template will trickle down to your structural directive.